# How to calculate the modulation register for MSP430 UART?

Tags: c, uart, msp430

I'm using a [MSP430F5529](http://www.ti.com/product/msp430f5529) clocked at 1 MHz and want to use the UART at 9600 bauds. So far I did:

```
void UART_init(void) {
    UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST; // Reset the UART's state machine
    UCA0CTL0 |= UCMSB; // MSB first, 8n1 mode
    UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2; // SMCLK

    // 1 MHz/9600 baud = 104.666.
    // Rounding down to 104 = 9615 bauds

    UCA0BR0 = 104;
    UCA0BR1 = 0;

}
```

But now I don't understand how to choose the value of the modulation register (`UCA1MCTL`) so as to get as close to 9600 bauds as possible. The [MSP430Fx5xx user's guide](http://www.ti.com/litv/pdf/slau208m), at page 908, proposes to use `UCBRS_1`, but I don't understand how this value is reached.

[image: line on the user's guide]

How do I calculate this register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of calculators to simplify the process, such as this one;
[simple msp430 baud rate bit calculator](http://mspgcc.sourceforge.net/baudrate.html)

If you want more detailed information on how this is calculated I recomemend this [great tutorial by Gustavo Litovsky](http://www.glitovsky.com/Tutorialv0_3.pdf) Specifically section 12.3.5 on PDF page 101

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, @GustavoLitovsky is a [member of Electronics StackExchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/16539/gustavo-litovsky), albeit essentially inactive. Perhaps he would be willing to chime in as well.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh: Never noticed this thread until recently. Thank you.

Comment: In the latest version of the tutorial linked above, it's section 12.3.5 on PDF page 101.